# Weblogic - Cannot load driver: DB2XADataSource

Tags: db2, weblogic

I am trying to connect to a DB2 instance ( not implemented yet ) and therefore I followed the manual where it says that I have to adapt the following xml file:

```
%WL_HOME%\server\lib\jdbcdrivers.xml
```

with this entry

```
DatabaseVersion="DB2 Universal JDBC Driver Provider (XA)"
```

Afterwards, in the admin console I must adapt the Driver class name accordingly:

```
Driver Class com.ibm.db2.jdbc.DB2XADataSource
```

Furthermore, I copied the jar files to my classpath as well as to another folder ( there are many different manuals on the Internet )

This is my CLASSPATH

```
set JDBC_PATH=C:\jars;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\wlserver\server\lib\db2jcc.jar;...
set CLASSPATH=%JDBC_PATH%;%CLASSPATH%
```

This is my other folder

```
C:\jars\db2jcc.jar
C:\jars\db2jcc_license_cu.jar
C:\jars\db2jcc4.jar
C:\jars\db2java.zip ( this zip file I deployed in the same directory, too )
```

but I always get the following error when doing a test connection:

```
Connection test failed.
Cannot load driver: com.ibm.db2.jdbc.DB2XADataSource
```

Maybe, someone knows, what I am doing wrong here or what I have to change?

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it is nearly always the same :)
When you look for the error, you cannot find it, then you ask on stackoverflow and a few minutes later you find the error by yourself :)

The seems to be a typo, the ClassName must be:

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2XADataSource
```

and not

```
com.ibm.db2.jdbc.DB2XADataSource
```

Thanks everyone!